# How to add images to taxonomies in spreecommerce

Tags: spree

I want to set up product categories (or "taxonomies" as spreecommerce calls them) containing products.

Is there a way to add a photo to each of them so I can show them in some sort of overview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spree::Taxon supports an icon as shown here:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.2/core/app/models/spree/taxon.rb#L26-L31

If that doesn't work for your purposes you can add another paperclip image to the model following the [Logic Customization Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/logic.html), then adding it to the view where you want to show the photo as shown in the [View Customization Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/view.html).